# Xcode scaling image to 0 and then returning to original size.

Tags: xcode, uiview

I am new to objective-c and coding in general and I am having a difficult time trying to figure out a code I am trying to write for program. I want my image to scale to 0 when I push my button and then return to the original size. So far I am able to scale it to 0 but I have no idea how to return it to the original size.

```
 -(void)rotate_imageview
 { 
 [UIView animateWithDUration: 0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimateOptionCurveLinear
                    animations:^{
                    CGAffineTransform Scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
                    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAFffineTransformMakeTranslation(10.0, 10.0);
                    self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translate);
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    }];
```